# Skype: How to delete an account completely?

Tags: windows, skype

I'm looking for a way to delete a Skype account? using Skype 5.x and Windows 7..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this Skype Forum about removing a Skype account:

> [Can I remove a Skype Account?](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=54501)

Basically, your username is **removed from the public directory** after 72 hours of non use, and your profile is also deleted 72 hours after you last used Skype. If for some reason you *really* need to have *all* of your personal data removed from Skype's system, you can contact `delete@skype.com` for extreme circumstances.

You can also delete the local Skype data on your computer by typing `%AppData%` in the `Run`Command, and deleting the `Skype` folder that appears in the window...

Comment: @Nhinkle:run %AppData% will run on windows7?

Comment: @Albouazizi: just type %AppData% in the textbox you got when you press the start button

Comment: @AlBouazizi, yes that is correct. FYI, @studiohack was the one who answered the question; I just edited his answer ;)

Comment: you're welcome @AlBouazizi :)

Comment: @Studiohack: Thank you for your answer, it helped alot.. finaly i found the correct way to clear the drop down username.. Thanx alot

Comment: The email address suggested to have the account permanently deleted no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Skype usernames "cannot" be deleted.  Once created, it will remain in Skype database/servers indefinitely.  It is true that it may be tagged as inactive if you haven't accessed it for a certain period of time (I think 60 or 90 days), but you can re-activate it by contacting customer service and requesting for a new password (the original one will no longer work).

So you just need to abandon your account if you have no more intentions to use it, and you can delete your account profile first before doing that so no one could identify you as the owner of that account.

Answer (score 1):

I've just deleted a Skype account, and followed the following steps:

1. Log in to support: http://www.skype.com/go/support.login
2. Select "Account and Password", "Deleting an account".
   [image]
3. Ignore the "Possible answers to your question" box and hit the "Continue support request" button.
4. At the "How would you like to contact us" screen, click on the "Start a chat" button.
   [image]
5. A new chat session will open.

Make it obvious that you want to delete your account. Then, the Skype representative will transfer you to another queue. You have to provide your first name, Skype name, and verify your identity. In my case, I had to provide:

- The month+year of registration (look at the date of your activation mail).
- The country from where I registered my account.
- The email address I used to register.
- Names of three of my Skype contacts (if any).

After a few minutes, I received a mail that my registered email address was changed to `delete@skype.com`. After that, I was not able to log in again using the same credentials, but my existing Skype session was still valid. I used this opportunity to change my personal information to "Deleted", because this seems not to be done automatically.

Comment: I did this and they removed my data from the server but it still appears on the p2p skype network with my phone number etc. Their support guy wrote: "We understand your concern that your deleted Skype account is still showing in Skype directory. ... Due to the technical nature of the peer-to-peer network... " They are a fail!

Comment: I manually wiped my information before contacting Skype. The only meaningful remaining information is my original Skype name. That's not a problem, at least no-one else will take it.